# How to solve the differential equation $y' = 2y(x\sqrt{y}-1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation in question is $y' = 2y(x\sqrt{y}-1)$.
I know I have to use a substitution, so I have tried multiple (including $v=\sqrt{y}$, which brought me close but not there). However, I can't seem to find the right one.
Even a hint towards the right substitution would help me. Thanks!

Comment: This is a Bernoulli equation, so try $v=y^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is $y'(x)=2y(x)[x\sqrt{y(x)}-1].$ Let $z(x)=\sqrt{y(x)},$ hence $z(x)^2=y(x),$ implying $2z(x)z'(x)=y'(x),$ hence $2z(x)z'(x)=2z(x)^2[xz(x)-1].$ This implies $z'(x)=z(x)[xz(x)-1].$ This is equivalent to $z(x)=0,$ or to $$z'(x)=z(x)^2\left[x-\frac1{z(x)}\right].$$ The latter is equivalent to $$-\frac{z'(x)}{z(x)^2}=\frac1{z(x)}-x.$$ Let $f(x)=\frac1{z(x)},$ thus $f'(x)=-\frac{z'(x)}{z(x)^2},$ hence $$f'(x)=f(x)-x.$$ This is equivalent to $f'(x)-1=f(x)-(x+1).$ Notice that if $g(x)=f(x)-(x+1),$ then $g'(x)=f'(x)-1.$ Therefore, $g'(x)=g(x).$ As such, $g(x)=Ce^x$ for some $C\in\mathbb{R}.$ Unraveling, we have that $f(x)=x+1+Ce^x,$ and $$z(x)=\frac1{x+1+Ce^x},$$ and so, $$y(x)=\frac1{(x+1+Ce^x)^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll let $z=\sqrt y$. Then $z^2=y$, so $\frac{dy}{dx}=2z\frac{dz}{dx}$.

Your DE turns into $2zz'=2z^2(xz-1)$, $z'=xz^2-z$, $\frac1z+\frac{z'}{z^2}=x$.

Let $v=\frac1z$, then $-v'=\frac{z'}{z^2}$.

$v-v'=x$, so $-(e^{-x}v)'=e^{-x}v-e^{-x}v'=xe^{-x}$.

$v=e^x\int{-xe^{-x}}dx=e^x((x+1)e^{-x}+C)=Ce^x+x+1$.

$$y=z^2=\frac1{v^2}=\frac1{(Ce^x+x+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following DE:

$$\text{y}'\left(x\right)=\text{n}\text{y}\left(x\right)\left(x\sqrt{\text{y}\left(x\right)}-\text{k}\right)\tag1$$

We can rewrite the equation:

$$\text{y}'\left(x\right)+\text{kn}\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{n}x\text{y}\left(x\right)^\frac{3}{2}\tag2$$

Dividing both sides by $-2\text{y}\left(x\right)^\frac{3}{2}$:

$$-\frac{\text{y}'\left(x\right)}{2\text{y}\left(x\right)^\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{\text{kn}}{2\sqrt{\text{y}\left(x\right)}}=-\frac{\text{n}x}{2}\tag3$$

Let $\text{v}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{y}\left(x\right)}}$, which gives $\text{v}'\left(x\right)=-\frac{\text{y}'\left(x\right)}{2\text{y}\left(x\right)^\frac{3}{2}}$. So:

$$\text{v}'\left(x\right)-\frac{\text{kn}\text{v}\left(x\right)}{2}=-\frac{\text{n}x}{2}\tag4$$

Now, let $\mu\left(x\right)=\exp\left(\displaystyle\int-\frac{\text{kn}}{2}\space\text{d}x\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{\text{kn}x}{2}\right)$. Multiply both sides by $\mu\left(x\right)$, substitute $-\frac{\text{kn}\exp\left(-\frac{\text{kn}x}{2}\right)}{2}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{\text{kn}x}{2}\right)\right)$ and apply the reverse product rule:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{\text{kn}x}{2}\right)\text{v}\left(x\right)\right)=-\frac{\text{n}x\exp\left(-\frac{\text{kn}x}{2}\right)}{2}\tag5$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$, evaluate the integrals and divide both sides by $\mu\left(x\right)$. Now you can solve for $\text{y}\left(x\right)$ by using $\text{y}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\text{v}\left(x\right)^2}$.